# Suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $F$. If $\alpha$ is also a root of $f(x)\in F[x]$, how can I prove that $p(x)$ divides $f(x)$?

Comment: $0=f(\alpha)=q(\alpha)p(\alpha)+r(\alpha)=r(\alpha)$. But either $r=0$ or $\deg r<\deg p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Consider the division of $f(x)$ by $p(x)$, $f= qp+r$ where $deg(r)<deg(p)$, $f(\alpha)=p(\alpha)=0$ implies $r(\alpha)=0$ since $p$ is the minimal polynomial, $r=0$.